# Cleanup older SNS subscriptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, mobile, amazon-sns

As a team we inherited an project that is using Amazon SNS to publish mobile notifications to mobile apps, this system is already active for multiple years.

The system works as following

- We create a customer specific Topic
- We register a new endpoint with the GCM or APN token

We noticed in older setups we had some stale endpoint data e.g. of apps that where reinstalled, uninstalled, ...

We would like to do 2 things

- Cleanup that older endpoints that are not active anymore (Can we do this purely on the "status" of the endpoint?)
- Actively react on when a device comes inactive - I read on how you can subscribe on "EndpointUpdated" events with an http endpoint - but it's not clear to me how can we determine that the "EndpointUpdated" is an uninstall, ... so we could clean this up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Python 3.6
2. Boto3
3. Need to Configure AWS Profile Account in your Local.

```
import boto3


def start_process(aws_profile_name):
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_profile_name)
    sns_client = session.client('sns')
    print("Started Process")
    list_of_sns = sns_client.list_topics()
    list_of_topics = [x.get("TopicArn") for x in list_of_sns.get('Topics')]
    for topic in list_of_topics:
        try:
            subscriptions = sns_client.list_subscriptions_by_topic(TopicArn=topic)
            list_of_subscription = [s.get("SubscriptionArn") for s in subscriptions.get('Subscriptions')]
            unsubscribe(list_of_subscription, sns_client)
            sns_client.delete_topic(TopicArn=topic)
            print(f"Successfully Deleted Topic - {topic}")
        except Exception:
            print(f"Failed to delete the sns - {topic}")
    subscriptions = sns_client.list_subscriptions()
    print(subscriptions)
    list_of_subscription = [s.get("SubscriptionArn") for s in subscriptions.get('Subscriptions')]
    unsubscribe(list_of_subscription, sns_client)


def unsubscribe(subscription_arn: list, sns_client):
    for arn in subscription_arn:
        try:
            sns_client.unsubscribe(SubscriptionArn=arn)
            print(f"Successfully unsubscribe - {arn}")
        except Exception:
            print(f"Failed to unsubscribe - {arn}")


print("""
Here Profile name like where access key 
and secret key you stored Locally

To See
--------------------------
cat ~/.aws/creddential
To Add new One:
--------------------------
aws configure --profile <your custom profile name>

""")
profile_name = input(f"Enter the profile name (i;e  'archive'): ")
start_process(profile_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to delete the subscriptions that are not in any topic:

```
from typing import Set

import boto3


def get_all_subscriptions() -> Set[str]:
    """
    Get all subscription ARNs.

    Returns:
        Set[str]: Set of subscription ARNs.
    """
    # Initialize the SNS client
    sns = boto3.client("sns")

    all_subscriptions = set()

    # Pagination loop
    next_token = None
    while True:
        # Get subscriptions with pagination
        response = (
            sns.list_subscriptions(NextToken=next_token) if next_token else sns.list_subscriptions()
        )

        # Extract subscription ARNs and add to the set
        all_subscriptions.update({sub["SubscriptionArn"] for sub in response["Subscriptions"]})

        # Check if there are more subscriptions to fetch
        next_token = response.get("NextToken")
        if not next_token:
            break

    return all_subscriptions


def get_subscriptions_in_topics() -> Set[str]:
    """
    Get all subscription ARNs that are subscribed to topics.

    Returns:
        Set[str]: Set of subscription ARNs in topics.
    """
    # Initialize the SNS client
    sns = boto3.client("sns")

    all_subscriptions_in_topics = set()

    # Pagination loop
    next_token = None
    while True:
        # Get all topics with pagination
        response = sns.list_topics(NextToken=next_token) if next_token else sns.list_topics()

        # Extract topic ARNs
        for topic in response["Topics"]:
            # Get subscriptions for each topic with pagination
            next_sub_token = None
            while True:
                # Get subscriptions for the current page
                sub_response = (
                    sns.list_subscriptions_by_topic(
                        TopicArn=topic["TopicArn"], NextToken=next_sub_token
                    )
                    if next_sub_token
                    else sns.list_subscriptions_by_topic(TopicArn=topic["TopicArn"])
                )
                # Extract subscription ARNs and add to the set
                all_subscriptions_in_topics.update(
                    {sub["SubscriptionArn"] for sub in sub_response["Subscriptions"]}
                )

                # Check if there are more subscriptions to fetch for this topic
                next_sub_token = sub_response.get("NextToken")
                if not next_sub_token:
                    break

        # Check if there are more topics to fetch
        next_token = response.get("NextToken")
        if not next_token:
            break

    return all_subscriptions_in_topics


def find_stale_subscriptions() -> Set[str]:
    """
    Find stale subscriptions that are not subscribed to any topic.

    Returns:
        Set[str]: Set of stale subscription ARNs.
    """
    all_subscriptions = get_all_subscriptions()
    subscriptions_in_topics = get_subscriptions_in_topics()

    # Find stale subscriptions
    stale_subscriptions = all_subscriptions - subscriptions_in_topics

    return stale_subscriptions


def delete_stale_subscriptions(stale_subscriptions: Set[str]) -> None:
    """
    Delete stale subscriptions.

    Args:
        stale_subscriptions (Set[str]): Set of stale subscription ARNs.

    Returns:
        None
    """
    # Initialize the SNS client
    sns = boto3.client("sns")

    # Delete stale subscriptions
    for subscription_arn in stale_subscriptions:
        sns.unsubscribe(SubscriptionArn=subscription_arn)
        print(f"Deleted subscription: {subscription_arn}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stale_subscriptions = find_stale_subscriptions()
    if stale_subscriptions:
        print(f"Stale subscriptions found: {stale_subscriptions=}")
        delete_stale_subscriptions(stale_subscriptions)
    else:
        print("No stale subscriptions found.")
```